# What is parentHWnd parameter used in some ArcObjects methods?

Tags: arcobjects

So the parameter **parentHWnd** appears in a number of ArcObjects methods, such as [IExportOperation.ExportFeatureClass.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00290000002m000000)

Does anyone know what the parameter is?

I can't seem to find any explanation. The only value I've ever passed to it is 0. Passing 1 threw an exception that I didn't recognise.

The reason I ask is because I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to hide the "exporting features" progress dialogue that pops up when you call this method, and I'm wondering if this has something to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are couple of Google searches that explain what it is:

http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson08.htm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979055%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#feedback

From what I understand (and could be wrong) its just a number that is used to indicate what the parent window is. So I don't think you can use it to control the visibility of the progress dialogue.

Comment: Thanks - not sure why I couldn't find that information. Any ideas for hiding the progress window? It's annoying me that I can't seem to export silently.

Comment: I haven't found a way to export silently, but in my addins, I get the parentHWnd using the syntax `My.ArcMap.Application.hWnd`